# Sharepoint Online storage metrics showing incorrect data

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Sharepoint online site collection storage metrics is showing incorrect data usage. For example It is showing 3 GB utilized space for document library with only 1.3 content.

I opened the document library in windows explorer and it is showing correct size there. Is there any timer job that needs to run before i come to conclusion and raise ticket to Micorosft Support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if the document library has versions enabled. While the total storage of the latest versions is only 1.3GB, it's likely that retaining a number of versions have pushed that amount up to 3GB. To minimize the storage impact, you can [change the number of versions saved or disable versioning](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37) on that document library or list.

You can view the storage metrics page at `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/_layouts/15/StorMan.aspx`. This will show both the site of the latest document as well as view the Version History with the size of each previous version.

Comment: Thanks Zach. It helped. I removed versioning and storage space decreased